# What do $S$, $M$, and $A$ mean in quark/color theory?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, quarks

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model)

> [...]below, and symmetric in flavor, spin and space put together. With three flavors, the decomposition in flavor is
> $$ \mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3} =\mathbf{10}_{S}\oplus \mathbf {8} _{M}\oplus \mathbf {8} _{M}\oplus \mathbf {1} _{A} $$
> The decuplet is symmetric in flavor, the singlet antisymmetric and the two octets have mixed symmetry. The space and spin parts of the states are thereby fixed once the orbital angular momentum [...]

What do S, M and A mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quote already contains the answer: **S**ymmetric, **a**ntisymmetric and **m**ixed.